# Sublime Text creating multiple div with same class using Shift

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap, sublimetext3

I am trying to create multiple div with same class using Shift command in sublime Text.But it doesnt work.

I am trying like this:

```
div.3x col-sm-4
```

Desired Output Like This:

```
   <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
   <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
   <div class="col-sm-4"></div>
```

How can we do this?

Comment: Not directly answering your question, but you can try [Emmet](https://github.com/sergeche/emmet-sublime#readme)

Comment: Belive it, I tried many times :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Step 1:** install [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/installation).

**Step 2:** Shift+Ctrl+p then search emmet to install and hit enter or watch this video 
[Sublime Text Emmet (Tutorial #7)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U4lFXtLF5Cs&list=PLpcSpRrAaOaqQMDlCzE_Y6IUUzaSfYocK&index=7)

That's it you're done installation Now restart sublime text.

=============================================================

and You'll get desired result by writing code like this

```
div.col-sm-4*3
```

then Hit Tab and you'll get

```
<div class="col-sm-4"></div>
<div class="col-sm-4"></div>
<div class="col-sm-4"></div>
```

but emmet must be install .

Comment: Again 3x not a class.Creating div with same class 3 times

Comment: you can get desired result by div.col-sm-4*3

Comment: But emmat package must be installed in sublime text editor

Comment: I removed the Package Control code from your answer, as it is subject to change at any time. There's even a nice orange boxed WARNING on the page you linked to telling you not to repost the code on other sites.

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
div.col-sm-4*3
```

For above code I assume that col-sm-4 is your class name and 3 is multiplication number which repeat three times div.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this 
`div.3x col-sm-4`

In your code may be you forget to put (-) between sm and 4. Try above code, may be its help you.

Answer (score 0):

Write every class with a single dot(.) and multiply it using `*` with your desire number. I assume you have a class `col-sm-4` and you want to make 3 `div`.

In this case you should write this

```
div.col-sm-4*3
```

Comment: 3x not a class.It indicates that div will create 3 times with same class.